# How do I create a notched widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a notched widget in Flutter like the one in this image [image]. Where I can create a notch on another widget like so.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

I have not seen much resource on this issue online but I know the bottom navigation bar can be notched

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a widget like that u can't do it with built-in widgets.

You should use custom clipper. Well i cant give you exact implementation since it would be too hard to produce by just looking at.

Its basically ordering series of command to flutter engine to render unorthodox geometrical shapes.

For ex. it's like go 200 pixel on +x axis, go with 300 +y axis. Make an arc with that tangents 4 point.

For detailed information you can use this article.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6